# Disable ECS applications to not read messages from aws sqs

Tags: amazon-web-services, cluster-computing, amazon-ecs, amazon-sqs

We have have introduced asynchronous processing in our application by introducing aws sqs (simple queue service). We are using blue/green deployment model where when we do new deployment, we deploy that to in-active region (blue/green) and after verifying in-active region, we enable it and make it active production. As we have sqs so we need to make sure when we are doing new deployment, new in-active deployment does not read messages from queue until it is turned to become active. At the same time, we also want to disable in-active (blue/green) to not read messages from queue. I am not aware of any inbuilt aws or sqs features. Anyone has any suggestions on how to achieve this behavior?

Appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

I gather from your question that the SQS queues are static in the sense that the stay the same throughout the blue/green deployments and that you want to be able to finish a new deployment and then somehow trigger the switchover once some kind of initial testing/verification is complete.

I don't know of a native AWS feature that would support this except for IAM.  If you created separate roles for blue and green, you could revoke one's permission to read from SQS and then grant that permission to the other deployment.

Other options are basically a variation on this theme of having some other piece of data that is consulted by the application to determine if it should service the queue:

- Use IAM as mentioned above to control the switchover
- Use a database field or a Parameter Store value to control the switchover and modify your code to check it.

Comment: Thanks Cargo23. Its not feasible in our application to have 2 separate IAM roles since we still want new deployment to be verified initially by dropping some messages into queue and have those processed by new deployment.